# Prove inequality with multiple integral

Tags: multiple-integral

$$\iint\limits_{Q} \frac{dx\,dy}{x^{-1}+|\ln y| - 1} \le 1 ,~~ Q = [0; 1] \times [0;1]$$

Comment: Please close this question, exactly the same question has been asked a few hrs ago here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043275/prove-the-inequality-involving-multiple-integrals   Maybe it's a homework question?